# Python equivalents to LINQ

Tags: python, functional-programming, iterator, method-chaining, fluent-interface

In C#, with LINQ, if I have en enumeration `enumerable`, I can do:

```cs
// a: Does the enumerable contain an item that satisfies the lambda?
bool contains = enumerable.Any(lambda);

// b: How many items satisfy the lambda?
int count = enumerable.Count(lambda);

// c: Return an enumerable that contains only distinct elements according to my custom comparer
var distinct = enumerable.Distinct(comparer);

// d: Return the first element that satisfies the lambda, or throws an exception if none
var element = enumerable.First(lambda);

// e: Returns an enumerable containing all the elements except those
// that are also in 'other', equality being defined by my comparer
var except = enumerable.Except(other, comparer);
```

I hear that Python has a more concise syntax than C# (and is therefore more productive), so how do I achieve the same with an iterable in Python, with the same amount of code, or less?

Note: I don't want to materialize the iterable into a list if I don't have to (`Any`, `Count`, `First`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following Python lines should be equivalent to what you have (assuming `func`, or `lambda` in your code, returns a Boolean):

```
# Any
contains = any(func(x) for x in enumerable)

# Count
count = sum(func(x) for x in enumerable)

# Distinct: since we are using a custom comparer here, we need a loop to keep 
# track of what has been seen already
distinct = []
seen = set()
for x in enumerable:
    comp = comparer(x)
    if not comp in seen:
        seen.add(comp)
        distinct.append(x)

# First
element = next(iter(enumerable))

# Except
except_ = [x for x in enumerable if not comparer(x) in other]
```

References:

- [List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [Generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)
- [`any()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any)
- [`sum()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum)
- [`set` type](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Note that I renamed `lambda` to `func` since `lambda` is a keyword in Python, and I renamed `except` to `except_` for the same reason.

Note that you could also use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) instead of the comprehensions/generators, but it is generally considered less readable.

Comment: Thanks, you missed d: enumerable.First(lambda), can you add it?

Comment: @Flavien - Added it, I also modified the `enumerable.Distinct` equivalent.  My original version was giving a set of the comparer results, instead of using the values from the original enumerable.

Comment: Without the custom comparer, you can just use `distinct = set(enumerable)`

Comment: What about performance? Is it good as .Net equivalent?

Comment: why `sum()` and not `len()`?

Answer (score 23):

The original question was how to achieve the same functionality with iterables in Python.  As much as I enjoy list comprehensions, I still find LINQ more readable, intuitive and concise in many situations.  The following libraries wrap Python iterables to achieve the same functionality in Python *with the same LINQ semantics*:

- [py_linq](https://pypi.org/project/py_linq/)
- [Linq](https://pypi.org/project/Linq/)

If you want to stick with built in Python functionality, [this blog post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/linq-in-python-for-c-sharp) provides a fairly thorough mapping of C# LINQ functionality to built-in Python commands.

Answer (score 9):

We have generator expressions and various functions for expressing arbitrary conditions over iterables.

```
any(some_function(e) for e in iterable)
sum(1 for e in iterable if some_function(e))
set(iterable)
next(iterable)
(e for e in iterable if not comparer(e) in other)
```

would roughly correspond to how you write your examples in idiomatic Python.

Comment: while that's cute and all it becomes a horrible mess once you want to chain multiple actions together, which is super trivial in linq.

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is five years old I don't know why nobody mentioned the beautiful [pipe](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe) library. It has a very beautiful interface and is also very extensible.

I usually add these functions to it:

```
@Pipe
def collect(iter, f):
    return f(iter)

@Pipe
def reduce(iterable, function, initial=None):
    return functools.reduce(function, iterable, initial)

_sum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, 0)
_len = reduce(lambda x, _: x + 1, 0)
```

so I can have something like

```
my_numbers = (
    count(1)
    | where(lambda n: n%2 == 0)
    | take_while(lambda n: n < 100)
    | collect(list)
)

my_numbers_len = my_numbers | _len
my_numbers_sum = my_numbers | _sum
```